# Concatenate entries from all incomplete rows with entries in complete rows above them

Tags: vba, excel, concatenation, data-cleaning

I converted a few files containing huge price lists from *.pdf to *.xls format using an online file format converter. However the conversion didn't give the desired result and more cleanup work is needed on the file. Have tried various different approaches using the macro recorder and tack overflow and have failed.

I need a macro that does the following cleanup work on my data.

1. Loops through rows in the selected data and Search for incomplete rows that are missing an entry in one or more cells.
2. Concatenate the text in these incomplete rows with the cell in the same column in the first complete row above it.

Example;

If row A contains all entries, but row B is missing entry in the Product code column then the entry in the needle description column in row B should concatenate with the needle description in row A

This file contain 10 line of data. Tab 1 shows the data that contains incomplete rows for the first 2 products. Tab 2 shows the form i want it to be in.

http://www.filetolink.com/5e39eaaf00

I'd be very grateful for any help on this for it will save me a lot of head wringing.

Comment: Would it be possible to add to your question a text example of what you have and what you want? I am hesitant to download files, but would like to help on this.

Comment: Follow these steps, select entire range. Go to: Find & Select ---> Go to Special.  Select blank cells.  Hit `=` then the up arrow then Ctrl - Enter.  It should fill all the empty cells with a formula to equal the cell above.  Then you can copy and paste the values.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't pull up the file because that site has extreme safety risk warnings, but the below code will do what you want as far as I can tell.  If not, please clarify and I'll modify as necessary.

My Excel columns are in the following order:
ID, ProductCode, NeedleDescription

If your NeedleDescription isn't the first column to the right of your ProductCode this won't work.  Just let me know what order your columns are in and I'll modify as necessary.

1. Copy the below into a module
2. Highlight the range you desire to clean up
3. Run the macro "Cleanse"

It will loop through all rows and fill all empty cells with the concatenation of:
CurrentRowNeedleDescription & PreviousRowNeedleDescription

```
Sub Cleanse()
    'Fill an empty or blank cell in selection
    'with formula specified

    'First Highlight Affected Range, then run this macro

    Dim cell As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    'Set formula to include in empty cells
    'to be the description of existing row plus description of previous row

    'Test for empty cell. If empty, fill cell with value given
    For Each cell In Selection
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]&R[-1]C[1]"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope that helps!